# Google Cardboard SDK not working in Unity 5.4.1f (Gvr Controller script not loaded)

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I'm trying to use Google Cardboard SDK with Unity 5.4.1f (Free). After importing the unitypackage with SDK, I tried to run the demo scene, but I see only freezing camera. I can't look around with mouse, just static picture. And I see the errors in Console and Inspector tab. Here is the screenshot: 
[image: Unity screenshot]

I tried to import different versions of Cardboard SDK and also tried Unity 5.3, but got the same errors. Please help me, I don't know what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project is likely corrupted. Make sure that the version of Unity you have is **>** the version used to build the *Google Cardboard SDK*.

If that's not the problem, close Unity, delete the current *Google Cardboard SDK* project and plugin. Download fresh version [here](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk).

After downloading it, import the *GoogleVRForUnity.unitypackage* file. This should fix your problem.

**EDIT**:

Things changed in the latest Google VR SDK update. The VR Demo Scenes now require **VR
Technical preview** to work. You can get the latest Unity version for VR [here](https://unity3d.com/partners/google/daydream). Scroll down to the end of the page.
The latest version *5.4.2f2-GVR10*.

Once you download this version of Unity `UNITY_HAS_GOOGLEVR` will be defined in Unity and you can now run the *ControllerDemo* demo.

**Note**:

You **can** run the *DemoScene* scene in *Assets\GoogleVR\DemoScenes\HeadsetDemo* directory without downloading the Unity GVR version. Right click on the *Project* tab then click *Reimport All*.

You just **cannot** run the *ControllerDemo* scene in *Assets\GoogleVR\DemoScenes* directory without downloading the Unity GVR version.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but Google Cardboard SDK supports Unity 5.2.1 or later. I also tried to make new clean Unity project and import that sdk and again got these errors.

Comment: I never said anything about Unity supporting it or not. What I saying is that if that is built with another version that is greater than your Unity version, you will have corrupted product files when you try to open the **example project** since Unity will have problem reading them. The SDK should be fine if you create a new scene. Remember, I said, re-download it then re-import it from Unity not just re-import it.

Comment: It's built with Unity 5.2.1, so it's not a problem I think.

Comment: Ok. Re-download the SDK like I said.

Comment: Tried, still the same error. I also downloaded latest Unity version, downloaded latest SDK version and imported it to clean project. Still the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127089/discussion-between-programmer-and-user2166726).

Comment: Was going to comment. Please create a new question for new problem. I will see if I can help. You are welcome!