# No resource identifier found for attribute 'enableVrMode' in package 'android'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-vr

I've started working on converting a game into Virtual reality. For starting purposes, I've created an empty project and imported Google VR plugin. But when I want to create the build in cellphone, following error occurs:

> CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.
>       stderr[
>       AndroidManifest.xml:30: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'enableVrMode' in package 'android'

```
stdout[
Configurations:
 (default)`
```

I've searched internet, changed API levels, did everything I could. But it didn't worked. Need your help guys.

Comment: What version of Unity are you using? There is a technical preview with added Google VR compatibility (Unity 5.4.2f2-GVR13) https://unity3d.com/partners/google/daydream

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`enableVrMode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#enableVrMode) attribute was added in Android N. You will get this error if you are using anything less that this version.

Download *Android SDK Platform-Tools 24* and then *Android 7.0 (API 24)*. You can do this from Android Studio. That should solve your problem.

If this does not solve your problem, note that the latest Google VR SDK includes some API that requires *Unity VR Technical preview* to work.You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40347111/google-cardboard-sdk-not-working-in-unity-5-4-1f-gvr-controller-script-not-load) for more information.

Comment: Updating the SDK fixed it?

Comment: yeah I've already updated it and it worked. But now when I create build notification shows "ApK has stopped working."

Comment: I that is totally a different issue. You should create a new question with that error, your Unity version, Android version.

Comment: I meant to say, create a new question since this totally a different issue. It might be a bug.

Comment: Glad I was able to help.